# Get input value using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm implementing angular js and is trying to get the input box's value and store it into the local storage. The input is typed by user and it's refer to ip address.

Below is my html code:

```
  <div>
    <input ng-model="serverip">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Apply" ng-click="save()">
  </div>
```

Below is my js code:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.save= function() {
        console.log($scope.serverip);
        localStorage.setItem('serverip', $scope.serverip);
    };
})
```

Why is it by using the above coding, after I key in the ip address into the input box, the `$scope.serverip` I get is always undefine?

Comment: How do you bind your controller to the HTML?

Comment: I'm using the ionic platform

Comment: can you provide plunker or jsfiddle with problem?

Answer (score 1):

I kinda find out the correct answer. We have to pass back the `serverip` in the html:

```
  <div>
    <input ng-model="serverip">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Apply" ng-click="save(serverip)">
  </div>
```

And in the js file:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.save = function(serverip) {
        console.log(serverip);
        localStorage.setItem('serverip', serverip);
    };
})
```

Comment: `$scope.save` already has access to `$scope.serverip`. Passing it manually is unnecessary, and just avoids the data binding Angular is built to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly set `ng-app` and `ng-controller`? Here's [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZjENXVxFbwsq9zBF72Q) demonstrating the behavior you want.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div>
    <input ng-model="serverip">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Apply" ng-click="save()">
  </div>
  <p>
    Saved IP: {{savedip}}
  </p>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.savedip = $scope.serverip
    };
})
```

Comment: Yes. I think my ng-app and ng-controller is correct. Just that I always get undefined for $scope.serverip. If my ng-app and ng-controller is wrong, I think the $scope.save function will not run. Now, the $scope.save button got run.

Comment: This is nice. Instead of saving it as a angularjs. is it possible to save that value as an java object? I need to pass that value into my classes

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect working example of what you are looking:

Live: http://jsbin.com/bifiseyese/1/edit?html,console,output

Code:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="serverip"/>
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('app',[]).controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.save = function(){
        localStorage.setItem('serverip', $scope.serverip);
        console.log("localStorage.serverip = " + localStorage.serverip);
    };
}]);
</script>
```